# Isomorphism problem for commutative algebras and schemes.

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry

Here's a question that I've wondered about somewhat idly from time to time.
I think it would be hard, but even a partial result would be interesting.
Hopefully someone here can make some headway.

Fix an algebraically closed field k (one can also relax this, e.g. k = $\mathbb{Q}$
is very interesting). Suppose that X and Y are two closed subschemes of affine or projective spaces over k given by explicit equations.

*Is there an algorithm to decide whether X and Y are isomorphic?*

A few comments.

1. I'm being a bit sloppy about the use of the word "algorithm". One can assume that the operations of k are Turing computable, or else choose a different model of computation.
2. For affine schemes, this can be stated as the isomorphism problem for finitely generated
   commutative k-algebras. I expect that the isomorphism problem for noncommutative finitely presented associative algebras would be false, since it seems close to the corresponding problem for groups which is undecidable. But the reduction is not quite clear to me. Is this known?
3. To give a positive solution, one would need an effective threshold d, so that either
   there is no isomorphism at all or there exists an isomorphism defined by a rational expression with degree (of the numerator and denominator) bounded by $d$. I have no
   feeling for whether this reasonable or not.
4. For the simplest case, where X is a smooth projective plane curve, a positive
   solution would amount showing that the corresponding point in the moduli space $M_g$, is
   computable ($g= (deg X-1)(deg X-2)/2$ ).  This looks challenging, but somehow it feels tractable to me.

Added Note: While I think spontaneous discussion is good, I would like to encourage
anyone who has a substantial result about this to write it down carefully and perhaps post it on the arxiv.

Answer (score 18):

Those are very nice questions.  In fact, I too have been asking these questions: see the last few slides in [this file](http://www-math.mit.edu/~poonen/slides/cantrell3.pdf).
Here are a few comments.

2) If you had an algorithm to decide isomorphism of finitely presented noncommutative $k$-algebras, applying it to group algebras $kG$ associated to finitely presented groups $G$ would let you decide whether a finitely presented group is trivial, but that is a well-known undecidable problem.  So this isomorphism problem is undecidable.

4) To decide whether two smooth projective curves over $\overline{\mathbb{Q}}$ are isomorphic, first compute the genus of each curve.  Assume that they are the same, both equal to $g$.  If $g=0$, they are isomorphic.  If $g=1$, compute Weierstrass models and then $j$-invariants.  If $g \ge 2$, compute tricanonical embeddings (i.e., associated to the linear system $|3K|$), and try to solve the equation that says that a linear automorphism of the ambient projective space sends one curve to the other.  This solves the problem for curves.  An extension of this idea solves the problem in higher dimensions whenever one of the varieties is of general type.  (I think this was first observed by Burt Totaro.)

As far as I know, all your other questions are open.  In particular, it is not clear whether one can relate them to Hilbert's tenth problem over $\mathbb{Z}$ or $\mathbb{Q}$ (or to undecidable problems like the word problem for finitely presented groups).

Comment: Thanks for your comments. It's nice to know you've been thinking about this also.

Comment: A related question is to decide whether or not a variety has a non-trivial automorphism. Do you know if this is known?

Comment: That's unknown too, I think.  The closest I've been able to come to this is this paper: http://www-math.mit.edu/~poonen/papers/automorphism.pdf

Answer (score 1):

The argument that I had is flawed and I do not know how to fix it. Here is a short description of one part that I cannot address. We are given two polarized K3 surfaces *X* and *Y* of degrees *x* and *y* respectively. It is clear that we can check if *X* and *Y* are isomorphic as polarized surfaces, but we would like to check if they are isomorphic as surfaces. If we could prove that there were finitely many polarizations on *X* having degree *y* and this finite set were computable, then we would be done. Unfortunately, there could be infinitely many such polarizations on *X*.

For Abelian surfaces the situation is slightly better, since the number of polarisations with a given degree is finite (by a theorem of Narasimhan and Nori). To find the polarisations on an Abelian variety *A*, one possibility is to compute the orbits of the automorphism group of *A* on the Neron-Severi group of *A*. While this could be difficult over $\overline{\mathbb{Q}}$, it might be replaced by a similar statement modulo a prime of good reduction, where at least Picard numbers can be computed by the Tate conjecture. Also in this case, I do not know if there are further problems with this approach.

I believe that this kills completely my previous post!

Comment: 1) Are you sure that the ample divisors on Enriques surfaces are constant? (The fact that the Picard rank is constant does not impy this in general.)

2) Only principally polarised abelian surfaces correspond to genus 2 curves and there exist non-isomorphic genus 2 curves which have isomorphic Jacobians.


 

Comment: I've been a little sloppy: Enriques surfaces are probably ok, since they are all sextics in $P^3$ with double lines along the edges of a tetrahedron; this gives you the boundedness that seems needed. (Abelian surfaces in another comment, since they do not fit here!)

Comment: For abelian surfaces, construct the Kummer variety, realize the Kummer as a quartic in *P^3*, and project away from a node. You get a double cover branched along six lines that are tangent to the same conic: I believe that the Jacobian of the genus two curve that you obtain by considering the double cover of the conic branched along the six tangency points is at least isogenous to the initial Abelian surface. This should bound things enough to make the construction computable.

Comment: (I would like to emphasize further that the case that worries me most is the case of K3 surfaces.)

Comment: This looks interesting. I agree, however, that the K3 surface case
needs some clarification. To apply Torelli in a more conventional approach, I think you would need to compare the transcendental lattices. Somehow you're avoiding this issue, but I'm not quite sure how.

Comment: I didn't understand the details of your argument for K3's at all, so didn't comment earlier. Firstly, I do not see how you get an isomorphism of the resuctions mod p of the two surfaces if you know that the (rational) Picard lattices are isomorphic. Secondly, an isomorphism mod p need not lift to an isomorphism so I do not see how you can use this. Perhaps you can expand your answer a little?

Comment: For the abelian case, the Kummer is a quartic in P^3 only in the principally polarised case. However, one can probably compute the endomorphism ring of an abelian variety and then also all the polarisations, so I agree that this case is probably OK.

Comment: Boundedness is OK for Enriques surfaces but it is not clear to me why that is enough since an isomorphism, if it exists, needn't preserve the sextic structure (as far as I can see).

Comment: I think the analogue of the Narasimhan-Nori theorem (only finitely many polarisations of a given degree upto automorphism) might be known for K3 surfaces; perhaps this follows from the "Kawamata-Morrison conjecture" on the structure of the nef cone of Calabi-Yau's which is known for K3 surfaces. However, I do not know if generators and relations for the automorphism group can be computed explicitly and even if they could it is not clear how one could use that to check for isomorphisms.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that one can embed 10th Hilbert problem over $\mathbb Z$ into this question, and for that the answer is not known.

Comment: Hilbert's 10th is undecidable over $\mathbb{Z}$, but
probably you meant $\mathbb{Q}$. Yes, I thought about that,
but the reduction isn't clear (to me).

Comment: Could you spell out this reduction? I don't see it. (Even assuming that you meant $\mathbb{Q}$, not $\mathbb{Z}$.)