# Testing isomorphism of finitely generated algebras

Tags: ra.rings-and-algebras, algorithms, ac.commutative-algebra, groebner-bases

Let $A=\mathbf{Q}[x_1,\ldots,x_n]$ be the polynomial ring in $n$ variables over the rational numbers. Let $B=\mathbf{Q}[f_1,\ldots,f_r]$ and
$C=\mathbf{Q}[g_1,\ldots,g_s]$ be two **finitely generated** $\mathbf{Q}$-subalgebras of $A$
with explicit generators.

Q1: Is there a finite time (efficient) algorithm that allows one to say when is $B\simeq C$ as $\mathbf{Q}$-algebra?

Q2: Is there a finite time (efficient) algorithm that allows one to say when is $Frac(B)\simeq Frac(C)$?

Here $Frac(B)$ denotes the fraction field. In both questions I really mean **isomorphic** and 
not equal.

Comment: I don't know much about algorithmic questions like this.  But: it would probably help to specify whether you are given a set of generators for $B$ and $C$, or whether you merely have some implicit description of these subalgebras.

Comment: Since $B$ and $C$ are both subalgebras of the same ring $A$, do you want to know whether they are isomorphic, or whether they are equal?

Comment: @David, here I really mean isomorphic. Equal would be "easy" since one may compute the relation ideal for $B$ and $C$ and then test for equality.

Comment: @MTS, yes in both cases I have explicit sets of generators.

Comment: http://mathoverflow.net/questions/21883/isomorphism-problem-for-commutative-algebras-and-schemes