# Algorithm to decide whether two quotient rings are isomorphic?

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, ac.commutative-algebra

Let $I_1,I_2\subset \mathbb{C}[x_1,\dots,x_n]=:R$ be two prime ideals (in practice we would probably work with $\mathbb{Q}$ instead). Is there an algorithm to decide whether
$$R/I_1\cong R/I_2$$
as $\mathbb{C}$-algebra's? i.e. whether $I_1$ and $I_2$ defined isomorphic varieties?

Comment: And probably $I_1$ and $I_2$ are input by a finite generating family.

Comment: @YCor Yes exactly.

Comment: Note that if you input finite sets $F_1,F_2$ of rational polynomials, the questions whether $\mathbf{Q}[x_1,\dots,x_n]/\langle F_1\rangle$ and $\mathbf{Q}[x_1,\dots,x_n]/\langle F_2\rangle$ are isomorphic, resp. whether $\mathbf{C}[x_1,\dots,x_n]/\langle F_1\rangle$ and $\mathbf{C}[x_1,\dots,x_n]/\langle F_2\rangle$ are isomorphic, are different.

Comment: @YCor Yes I realise that, but I'm curious about both questions. To point is that I'm actually most interested in the question over $\mathbb{C}$, but there is no hope of this being actually computable, hence the question over $\mathbb{Q}$, where more things do tend to be computable. Actually I guess we could work over $\overline{\mathbb{Q}}$.

Comment: You can work over an algebraically closed computable field (computable means that you can input its elements, compute operations, and determine whether two elements are equal).

Answer (score 6):

[Macaulay2](http://www2.macaulay2.com/Macaulay2/) has an algorithm to compute [minimal presentations](http://www2.macaulay2.com/Macaulay2/doc/Macaulay2-1.13/share/doc/Macaulay2/Macaulay2Doc/html/_minimal__Presentation_lp__Ideal_rp.html) of $I_1$ and $I_2$ ("compute a minimal presentation of the quotient ring defined by an ideal").  If those minimal presentation are equal (or otherwise observably isomorphic), then $R/I_1\cong R/I_2$.

I tried it with a few silly examples just now in Macaulay2, and it worked for those.  Maybe you will get lucky with the cases you are thinking about.

Answer (score 3):

Your question is a special case of the general problem of deciding whether two varieties are isomorphic. This question is discussed here:

[Isomorphism problem for commutative algebras and schemes.](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/21883/isomorphism-problem-for-commutative-algebras-and-schemes)

There is no known algorithm for this problem, and the problem is not known to be undecidable. I suspect the same is true for your problem.